# Google AdSense API explorer return all rows even when a maxResult as well

Tags: adsense, adsense-api

Have anyone else had a problem with Google AdSense API explorer returning all rows for a report even when MaxResult is set? It works for all other requests but not Accounts.reports.saved: generate.
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/reports/saved/generate

I have tried it with my own code as well using this http request https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/1.4/accounts/{accountId}/reports/{reportId}?maxResults={MAX_RESULTS}

This will also return a full set of rows.